# Disabled Umbraco users still appearing in backend

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I appreciate that you cannot delete users from Umbraco in the true sense of the word due to referential integrity within the SQL database should there be any nodes associated with them

I have a database that has had several dev/test users created over time and I need to deliver the database to a client.

If I disable a user (selecting both "Disable user" and "Disable Umbraco Access"), how can I stop them appearing in the list of users in the backend? I do not mind them remaining dormant in the database but do not want the client (who will be logging on as an Admin) see them

Comment: And what if you want to re-enable the user and you can't see them in your list?

Comment: Excellent point @Mivaweb - in this instance we would never want to do this but presumably setting the correct value in the cmsUmbracoUser table would reactivate them

Comment: I know you can create a custom listview for members but I haven't tried it for backend users. Then you could create a controller where you fetch all users that are not disabled and display them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update a setting in the `~/config/umbracoSettings.config` file.

```
  <security>
    <!-- change in 4.8: Disabled users are now showed dimmed and last in the tree. If you prefer not to display them set this to true -->
    <hideDisabledUsersInBackoffice>true</hideDisabledUsersInBackoffice>
  </security>
```

> This setting was introduced in v4.8. If it's set to true it's not
>   possible to see disabled users, which means it's not possible to
>   re-enable their access to the back office again. It also means you
>   can't create an identical username if the user was disabled by a
>   mistake.

Source: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/config/umbracosettings/#security

Comment: Something new learned today. Never saw this setting before! Thanks!

Comment: I think a lot of the settings have been removed by default from the standard installed version of umbracoSettings.config in favour of default values. You only need to add settings you wish to override. The page I linked above serves as a relatively good reference to the options you have available to you.